# Matplotlib - boundaries with changing figure size (using imshow)

Tags: python, matplotlib, border, figure, imshow

I have the following code (below) to produce a plot (a confusion matrix), and I want black lines between the squares, as below:

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf import FigureCanvasPgf
mpl.backend_bases.register_backend('pdf', FigureCanvasPgf)
pgf_with_rc_fonts = {'figure.figsize': (15,9.3)} # Usually much longer.
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_rc_fonts)
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
cm = np.array([[0.4, 0.6], [0.9, 0.1]])
classes = ['False', 'True']
plt.clf()
cmap = cmap=plt.cm.Blues
plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='none', cmap=cmap, aspect='equal', vmax=1, vmin=0)
plt.colorbar()
tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes)
plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)
plt.gca().set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, len(tick_marks), 1), minor=True)
plt.gca().set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, len(tick_marks), 1), minor=True)
plt.gca().grid(which='minor', color='k', linestyle='-')
plt.gca().tick_params('both', length=0, width=1, which='minor')
```

**Plots**

This produces the following plot:

[image: Original]

**The problem region**

And the annoying thing is that:either than the box is not of the correct height, else the y axis minor tick is too low. I am not sure which, but **it gives the ugly border**:

[image: Ugly]

However, when I remove the the parameter `'figure.figsize': (15,9.3)` this doesn't happen. I am unsure what is going wrong, but I want the larger figure sizes for nicer plots, and so I can use larger interactive plots.

Comment: This is a bug in matplotlib. I don't know where it comes from, but in general matplotlib 2.0 has introduced many inaccuracies like that. You may get a better result playing around with the figure height though, i.e. change 9.3 to 9.2 or some other values and see it get better. If you want you can report it on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, [I have raised it as an issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9015), but hope someone on stack overflow may know how to resolve/circumvent it.

Comment: As a workaround you could try to use a `pcolormesh` with `edgecolor` set to black instead of `imshow` with a `grid`.

Comment: @user8153, using `pcolormesh` and `edgecolor` as suggested does give a reasonable workaround, (but then has other issues of its own). Nonetheless, thanks for the suggestion, which I'm now using.